# Defining typings for npm react module for typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to define the typings for a react module, `react-input-autosize`, for use in a typescript project. The module has no ready-made typings.

I added a directory `react-input-autosize` to `typings/modules`.
Then I added a file `index.d.ts` to the new directory.
I filled the new file with my understanding of the structure of the imported module (which is accepted by the typescript compiler):

```
/// <reference path="../../globals/react/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../globals/react-dom/index.d.ts" />

declare module 'react-input-autosize' {
  import * as React from "react"
  import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom"

  export interface AutosizeInputProps extends React.Props<any>{
      className?: string,     
      defaultValue?: any,     
      inputClassName?: string,
      inputStyle?: any, 
      minWidth?: number,
      onKeyDown?: (x:any) => void,
      onChange?: (x:any) => void,
      placeholder?: string,
      placeholderIsMinWidth?: boolean,
      style?: any,  
      value?: string,
      readOnly?: boolean,
      autoFocus?: boolean,
      type?: string
    }

  export class AutosizeInput extends React.Component<AutosizeInputProps, any> {
      constructor(props? : AutosizeInputProps, context? : any);

      greeting: string;
      showGreeting(): void;
  }

  export default AutosizeInput;
}
```

At this point importing the module in the project started succeeding, in the sense that I get no "module not found" errors anymore by doing:

```
import AutosizeInput from 'react-input-autosize';
```

Instantiating the `AutosizeInput` class unfortunately now does not work at runtime, as `AutosizeInput` results to be undefined.

In a non-typescript file within the same project then `import AutosizeInput from 'react-input-autosize';` still works, so the module is correctly imported from npm when untyped.

Answer (score 0):

You `default` import:

```
import AutosizeInput from 'react-input-autosize';
```

Will try to import the `default` export. But the module `react-input-autosize` doesn't have a default export. Can you try with:

```
import * as AutosizeInput from 'react-input-autosize';
```

And removing `default` from your export:

```
export = AutosizeInput;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: With your suggestion I get `error TS2497: Module ''react-input-autosize'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`.

Comment: If I flag the class `AutosizeInput` as `export default`, then the compiler does not complain but I cannot instantiate the class in react as the symbol is apparently null. This means that for whatever reason I can get the typings to work, but then import does not load the class at runtime...